# How to run command on linux and save output in variable

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I use node.js and mocha plug-in.
I need to run tests from Jenkins.

Test dir is '/home/user/tests'
Through putty I can start command 'make all' to run tests and get result.
How can I run it from bash script?

I created script in file "start.sh":

```
    #!/bin/bash

    DIR=$(cd /home/user/tests; make all)

    echo "-----------------------START----$stDate--------------------"
    echo $DIR
    echo "------------------------END-----$enDate--------------------"
```

in this case result is

```
    08:10:58  SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [start.sh] ...
    08:10:59  /bin/sh: mocha: command not found
    08:10:59  /bin/sh: mocha: command not found
    08:10:59  /bin/sh: mocha: command not found
    08:10:59  /bin/sh: line 0: cd: ./messagel: No such file or directory
    08:10:59  -----------------------START----Mon Sep  3 08:11:00 EDT                 2012--------------------
    08:10:59  cd ./tenant; mocha; cd ../; cd ./user; mocha --reporter list; cd ../; cd ./asset; mocha; cd ../; cd ./messagel mocha -t 5000; cd ../;
    08:10:59  ------------------------END-----Mon Sep  3 08:11:00 EDT 2012--------------------
    08:10:59  SSH: EXEC: completed after 401 ms
```

but this is contained in file "makefile" and is not run
cd ./tenant; mocha; cd ../; cd ./user; mocha --reporter list; cd ../; cd ./asset; mocha; cd ../; cd ./messagel mocha -t 5000; cd ../;

Answer (score 3):

The fact your `DIR` variable only contains part of the output might be because `cd /home/user/tests; make all` outputs to stderr instead of stdout.

Try:

```
DIR=$(cd /home/user/tests; make all >& /dev/stdout)
```

to make sure you capture both the normal output and the output of the errors in your `DIR` variable.

Another possibility would be

```
DIR=$(cd /home/user/tests; make all 2>&1 )
```

which pretty much doe the same thing, except that it manipulates file descriptors directly. More info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Please also note that this only redirects the output of `make all`. In other words, if `/home/user/tests` does not exist, the error message will not be catched by the `$( )`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the bash script is being run under a different user ID than when you run it manually; a different value for the `PATH` variable means that the `mocha` and `messagel` commands are not being found when run from the Makefile.